# How to derive the Rotation Matrix from the Euler Formula

Tags: matrices, rotations

I'm trying to understand how the two dimensional rotation matrix (i.e. $R \in \mathbb{R}^2$) can be derived from the Euler Formula ($e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$). $R$ is given as:

$$
R(\theta) =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
  \sin\theta & \cos\theta
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  x' \\
  y'
 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
  \sin\theta & \cos\theta
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
  x' = x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta 
$$
$$
  y' = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta
$$

My questions are:

- Why can be $i$ omitted from the rotation matrix? (I tried to look for explanations [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions),[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04885) but none of these explanations goes beyond that  $i$ is omitted)
- Why can we derive a rotation matrix for $\mathbb{R}^2$ from a form that is defined in $\mathbb{C}^2$? How comes we don't get complex numbers as a result after some rotations?

Comment: As for your first question: A complex number can be regarded as a vector with the real part/component along the "$x$-axis" and imaginary part along the "$y$-axis", so the $i$ is just a way of distinguishing between the two dimensions of the complex number/vector; you can instead distinguish these by using the unit vectors of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Lovsovs Thank you for your comment. Perhaps I am just confused here and $e^\theta = sin(\theta) + cos(\theta)$ also applies without i included? I'm heaving hard time to get my head around why Real numbers can be rotated from a formula defined in the the domain of Complex numbers.

Comment: Use `&` to separate matrix elements that are on the same row so that they don’t run together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complex number $a+bi$ can be represented by the matrix $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$.

Note that $(a+bi)\pm(c+di)=(a\pm c)+(b\pm d)i$ and

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \pm\begin{pmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a\pm c & -(b\pm d) \\ b\pm d & a\pm c \end{pmatrix}$$

Also we have $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$ and

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} ac-bd & -(ad+bc) \\ ad+bc & ac-bd \end{pmatrix}$$